# calculate similarity between two vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, similarity

I have a matrix **M** which is a `29 x 18 double`, something like this:

```
1   1   1 ...
2   1   1 ...
3   1   2 ...
2   2   2 ...
2   1   3 ...
3   1   3 ...
1   3   3 ...
...
```

For each possible pair of two columns in **M**, I want to calculate the number of times the values of the same row between two columns are identical. Take column 1 and 2 for instance, the number of times values of the same row are identical is **2** since `M(1,1) = M(1,2)` and `M(4,1) = M(4,2)`. This calculation is repeated 18 time for each column as each column is paired with each of the total number of columns, including itself. Thus, the output (called **N**) would be 18 x 18 matrix with the each value indicating how many instances the values of the same row from the original two corresponding columns are identical. Something like this

```
29 4 5 3 ...
4 29 6 0 ...
5 6 29 7 ...
...
```

Since `N(2,1) = 4`, this would indicate that column **1** and column **2** matrix **M** have 4 matching values of the same row.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a double for loop like that:

```
result = zeros(18);
for i = 1:18
    for j = 1:18
        result(i,j) = nnz(M(:,i) == M(:,j));
    end
end
```